# Probability: (Imagine a 10 sided die) How would I calculate the probability of NOT rolling #1 (of the 10 sides) over a total of 100 roles?

Tags: probability

Furthermore, I would like to know how to find a "cascading" probability, if you will. For example: Probability for 100 roles, probability for 99 roles, probability for 98 roles, etc. (I am newer to the mathematics behind probability. Please do not hesitate to reference me to another posting)

Comment: Have you ever heard of a [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?  Let $p$ be the probability of rolling a 1.  Let $1-p$ then be the probability of not rolling a 1.  Conclude.

Comment: I haven't, it looks very interesting and applicable. Thank you for the great reference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each roll, the probability of not getting a $1$ is $\frac{9}{10}$. Since the rolls are independent events, the probability of never getting a $1$ in $k$ rolls is $( \frac{9}{10} )^k$. In the case of $k=100$, you get approximately 0.0027 %

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thank you very much.

Is there a simple way to calculate an estimated frequency of each sequence total? For example, I wish to construct a list of 1-100 and would like to estimate the frequency at which I would roll "#1" on four turns, five turns, six turns, up to 100 turns. 

Example: 100th roll: occurs 1 time for every 10,000 times I hit #1 on the 4th sequence (of consecutive rolls). This is over the span of say 1,000,000 rolls.

Comment: Just realized, would it be ((9/10)^k)*1,000,000

Comment: I don't understand the question. Since you seem to take into account the order of the rolls, there are exactly $10^k$ possible sequences of results, and they all have the same likelihood. If you are just interested in the sum at the end, though, your space of possible events is different: you can get any number from $k$ to $10k$, but not each number has the same probability of being achieved. I can't remember how this works exactly (maybe you can ask another question, if you're interested in the details), but it should be kind of a Gaussian distribution, with the peak around $5k$.

Comment: If you meant "probability of getting $n$ times $1$ at specific moments, over $k$ rolls", then it is $\frac{9^{(k-n)}}{10^k}$. If you just wanted to have, say, $n$ ones but you don't care where, then you should multiply the above probability times ${k \choose n}$.

Comment: If you're interested in this kind of things, I advise you to have a look at an introduction to combinatorics and probability. For the basic cases it's not so difficult and quite fun. More advanced probability theory requires quite a lot of measure and integration theory, but you should not worry about that too early.